# unable to use ssh key when spawning digitalocean droplet using terraform

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, digital-ocean, terraform

I am using terraform v0.10.6 to spin up a droplet on digitalocean.  I am referencing a key and SSH fingerprint that has already been added to digitalocean in my terraform config (copied below).  I am able to log onto existing droplets using this ssh key but not on a newly formed droplet (SSH simply fails).  Any thoughts on how to troubleshoot this so that when I launch the droplet via terraform, I should be able to log onto the droplet via the key that has already been added on digitalocean (and visible on DO console).  Currently, the droplet appears on the digitalocean admin console but I am never able to SSH onto the server (connection gets denied).

**test.tf**

```
# add base droplet with name
resource "digitalocean_droplet" "do-mail" {
  image              = "ubuntu-16-04-x64"
  name               = "tmp.validdomain.com"
  region             = "nyc3"
  size               = "1gb"
  private_networking = true

  ssh_keys = [
    "${var.ssh_fingerprint}",
  ]

  connection {
    user        = "root"
    type        = "ssh"
    private_key = "${file(var.private_key)}"
    timeout     = "2m"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin",
      "sudo apt-get update",
    ]
  }
}
```

**terraform.tfvars**

```
digitalocean_token = "correcttoken"
public_key = "~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
private_key = "~/.ssh/id_rsa"
ssh_fingerprint = "correct:finger:print"
```

**provider.tf**

```
provider "digitalocean" {
  token = "${var.digitalocean_token}"
}
```

**variables.tf**

```
##variables used by terraform

    # DO token
    variable "digitalocean_token" {
      type = "string"
    }

    # DO public key file location on local server
    variable "public_key" {
      type = "string"
    }

    # DO private key file location on local server
    variable "private_key" {
      type = "string"
    }

    # DO ssh key fingerprint
    variable "ssh_fingerprint" {
      type = "string"
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to setup a new droplet with the SSH key at initialization time when I specified the digitalocean token as an environment variable (as opposed to relying on the terraform.tfvars file).